# Is there a Linux tool for creating a DataURI of a given file?

Tags: linux, command-line, file

How can I easily obtain the DataURI of a file in a terminal-based environment? The tool should be installable via apt-get and feature simple syntax. Could you suggest some suitable options? Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Since data URIs are just a combo of mime type + base64 encoded contents, you can easily create your own script to create a full string. Example from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247846/562386):

```
#!/bin/sh
mimetype=$(file -bN --mime-type "$1")
content=$(base64 -w0 < "$1")
echo "url('data:$mimetype;base64,$content')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there was a built in tool for that. Typing `base64 file.txt > txtbase64.txt` will save the DataURI for `file.txt` inside `txtbase64.txt`.